# Polymorphic Enums

Tags: c++, enums, polymorphism

Polymorphic Enums?

> In C++, we often use polymorphism to allow old code to handle new
>   code--for instance, as long as we subclass the interface expected by a
>   function, we can pass in the new class and expect it to work correctly
>   with the code that was written before the new class ever existed.
>   Unfortunately, with enums, you can't really do this, even though there
>   are occasional times you'd like to. (For instance, if you were
>   managing the settings for your program and you stored all of them as
>   enum values, then it might be nice to have an enum, settings_t, from
>   which all of your other enums inherited so that you could store every
>   new enum in the settings list. Note that since the list contains
>   values of different types, **you can't use templates**.)
>
> If you need this kind of behavior, you're forced to store the enums as
>   integers and then retrieve them using typecasts to assign the
>   particular value to the setting of interest. And you won't even get
>   the benefit of dynamic_cast to help you ensure that the cast is
>   safe--you'll have to rely on the fact that incorrect values cannot be
>   stored in the list.

I'm quoting from a [C++ programming tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html).

Can anybody please explain more deeply and with some examples how Polymorphic Enums work?
And in the case I have templates?

Comment: I think it's clear from the quoted text that polymorphic `enums` don't work, at least in the simplest sense.  An `enum` is basically a named constant with an underlying integral storage type.  In any place where you would want to use a polymorhpic `enum`, there is likely a more elegant solution using templates.

Comment: Polymorphic enums don't make much sense and if you think you need them then chances are your design is shoddy. If you really need them then Boost.Variant should work.

Comment: @Chad can you help me understand better with a little code snippet example?

Comment: *polographic enums* makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Matteo, see my answer below, it's not "short" by any means :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply stated, an `enum` is simply a named constant value, for instance:

```
enum Settings
{
   setting_number_0,
   setting_number_1,
   setting_number_2,      
};
```

In the above example, `setting_number_X` is simply a named constant for the value `X`, as enumeration values start at 0 and increase monotonically.

Keeping these then, in some type of container gives a basic storage type of integers, but can still be somewhat typesafe.

```
std::vector<Setting> app_settings;

// this works
app_settings.push_back(setting_number_0);

// this is a compile time failure, even though the underlying storage
// type for Setting is an integral value.  This keeps you from adding
// invalid settings types to your container (like 13 here)
app_settings.push_back(13);

// but you also cannot (directly) add valid setting values (like 1)
// as an integral, this is also a compile time failure.
app_settings.push_back(1);
```

Now, suppose you wanted to add additional specific setting types and keep them all in a container.

```
enum DisplaySettings
{
   // ...
};

enum EngineSettings
{
   // ...
};
```

Now, if you wanted to keep all the settings in a single container, you cannot *safely*.  You could store all the integral values in a container of `std::vector<int>` or similar, but that breaks down in that you cannot determine what integral types belong to what setting enumerations.  Also, since the types are different you cannot store them in a single type-safe container.

The correct way to go about this is would be to store the functionality of the setting in the container, something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// This is our "base class" type so we can store lots of 
// different setting types in our container
class setting_action
{
public:
   // we enable the setting by calling our function
   void enable_setting()
   {
      setting_function_(this);
   }

protected:
   // This is a function pointer, and we're using it to get some
   // compile time polymorphism
   typedef void (*setting_function_type)(setting_action* setting);

   // these can only be constructed by derived types, and the derived
   // type will provide the polymorhpic behavior by means of the 
   // above function pointer and based on the derived type's handler
   setting_action(setting_function_type func)
      : setting_function_(func)
   {
   }

public:
   ~setting_action()
   {
   }

private:
   setting_function_type setting_function_;
};

// This is the derived type, and where most of the magic
// happens.  This is templated on our actual setting type
// that we define below    
template <class Setting>
class templated_setting_action
   : public setting_action
{
public:
   templated_setting_action(Setting setting)
      : setting_action(&templated_setting_action::enable_setting)
      , setting_(setting)
   {
   }

   // This function catches the "enable_setting" call from
   // our base class, and directs it to the handler functor
   // object that we've defined
   static void enable_setting(setting_action* base)
   {
      templated_setting_action<Setting>* local_this = 
         static_cast<templated_setting_action<Setting>*>(base);

      local_this->setting_();
   }

private:
   Setting setting_;
};

// this is just a shorthand way of creating the specialized types
template <class T>
setting_action* create_specialized_setting_action(T type)
{
   return
      new templated_setting_action<T>(type);
}

// Our actual settings:
// this one displays the user name    
struct display_user_name
{
   void operator()()
   {
      std::cout << "Chad.\n";
   }
};

// this one displays a short welcome message    
struct display_welcome_message
{
   void operator()()
   {
      std::cout << "Ahh, the magic of templates.  Welcome!\n";
   }
};

// now, we can have one container for ALL our application settings

std::vector<setting_action*> app_settings;

int main()
{
   // now we can add our settings to the container...
   app_settings.push_back(create_specialized_setting_action(display_user_name()));
   app_settings.push_back(create_specialized_setting_action(display_welcome_message()));

   // and individually enable them
   app_settings[0]->enable_setting();
   app_settings[1]->enable_setting();

   // also, need to delete each setting to avoid leaking the memory
   // left as an exercise for the reader :)
   return 0;
}
```